# Magento 2 : Display Blogs on Homepage (Magefan Blog Module)

Tags: magento2, blog

How to display all blogs on home page using **Magefan Blog** Module.

Please suggest me any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line in your template and you will get recent blog post list..

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magefan\Blog\Block\Widget\Recent")->toHtml(); ?>
```

Hope this will help you!